# How do I generate unique usernames on a shared database concurrently?

Tags: sql-server, database, concurrency, uniqueidentifier, identifier

I need to generate account names automatically. They will be used in user software that will access my service, so they are not necessarily pretty looking. I guess any alphanumeric string long enough will do. Assume I already have an algorithm that produces good enough alphanumeric string.

There're two major requirements: they must be unique and they will be generated concurrently. Specifically my service will run on multiple machines and all copies will access the same shared database. I need to generate those usernames in such way that no two nodes ever generate identical usernames.

How do I do this? Do I just leave this idea and use GUIDs? Is there a prettier way that GUIDs for this scenario?

Comment: @Bogdan Sahlean: SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 2):

One of:

- Use GUIDs (uniqueidentifier data type) but not as a clustered index
- Use an IDENTITY column

If SQL Server replication is used over multiple nodes (Edit: was thinking too much before)

- Use IDENTITY columns with ranges set per node (eg -1 to -1000000, 1 to 100000 etc)
- IDENTITY column and a NodeID column to separate the IDENTITY values

All are concurrency safe

Comment: @sharptooth: ah! if you mean client nodes then yes, the DB will. I was thinking of multiple nodes in SQL Server replication

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.CommonName
(
    CommonNameID INT IDENTITY(0,1) PRIMARY KEY
    ,Name NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
    ,LastID INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);
INSERT  dbo.CommonName(Name)
VALUES  
 ('JAMES')  
,('JOHN')   
,('ROBERT') 
,('MICHAEL')    
,('WILLIAM')    
,('DAVID')  
,('RICHARD')    
,('CHARLES')    
,('JOSEPH') 
,('THOMAS');
GO

--Test
CREATE TABLE [User](Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, UserName NVARCHAR(60));
GO

UPDATE  dbo.CommonName WITH(ROWLOCK)
SET     
        LastID = LastID + 1
OUTPUT  inserted.Name+CAST(inserted.LastID AS NVARCHAR(10)) INTO [User](UserName)
WHERE   CommonNameID = ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 10
GO 20 --We need 20 new users

SELECT  *
FROM    [User] u
ORDER BY u.Id;
--End of test
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.CommonName;
DROP TABLE dbo.[User];
```

Sample output:

```
Batch execution completed 20 times.
Id          UserName
----------- ------------------------------------------------------------
1           RICHARD1
2           MICHAEL1
3           ROBERT1
4           WILLIAM1
5           ROBERT2
6           JAMES1
7           CHARLES1
8           RICHARD2
9           JOSEPH1
10          THOMAS1
11          ROBERT3
12          MICHAEL2
13          WILLIAM2
14          MICHAEL3
15          THOMAS2
16          THOMAS3
17          WILLIAM3
18          RICHARD3
19          JAMES2
20          RICHARD4

(20 row(s) affected)
```

If you want to test this code for concurrency issues you can run `UPDATE ...; GO 100000` and `UPDATE ...; GO 100` in SSMS in two separated windows/queries and, at the end, you can run this query `SELECT UserName, COUNT(*) Num FROM dbo.[User] ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC` to see if you can find duplicates.